# Globalize accessors on subset of available locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, globalize

By design, some classes will deal with only a subset of available languages.

the `globalize-accessors` gem is quite useful, however, the rendering requires that the following be defined

```
Class.globalize_attribute_names
```

so while `available_locales = [:en, :ru, :fr, :de]`, the goal is to work with a smaller array `[:en, :ru]`

The [documentation](https://github.com/globalize/globalize-accessors) states `Calling globalize_accessors with no options will therefore generate accessor methods for all translated fields and available languages`.  But the purported way to invoke is in the model

```
globalize_accessors :locales => [:en, :fr], :attributes => [:title]
```

How can the `globalize_accessors`method refer to an array, something generated by the likes of

```
@post.owner.ownerlocales.pluck('locale')
```

(although the array values are quoted...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working solution found but that does not address the above question, is based on the fact that globalize-accessors

> gives you access to methods: title_pl, title_en, title_pl=, title_en=

Thus, a controller method that generates a whitelist

```
@locales =  []
@post.owner.ownerlocales.each do |ol|
  locale = ol.locale
  @locales.push(locale)
end
```

... then process in the view filtering out the globalize_processors from whitelist

```
<% Post.globalize_attribute_names.each do |lang| %>
  <% my_string = lang.to_s %>
  <% @locales.each do |locale| %>
    <% checkstring = "_" + locale %>
    <% if my_string.include? checkstring %>
      <div class="row">
        <%= t(lang[0..-4]) %> &nbsp;&nbsp;-&nbsp;&nbsp; <%= lang[-2, 2] %> <br />
        <%= f.text_area lang, rows: "3" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Not efficient, functional.